# Chef cloudera cookbook can't find missing dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hadoop, chef-infra, cloudera

I'm trying to create a `Cloudera's Hadoop` cookbook. I'm using [this cloudera](https://github.com/danielpoe/cloudera) cookbook to make it work:

```
# PSEUDEO INSTALL:
# https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Installing+CDH4+on+a+Single+Linux+Node+in+Pseudo-distributed+Mode#InstallingCDH4onaSingleLinuxNodeinPseudo-distributedMode-InstallingCDH4withYARNonaSingleLinuxNodeinPseudodistributedmode

if node[:platform] == "ubuntu"
    execute "apt-get update"
end

# Install required base packages
package "curl" do
    action :install
end

package "wget" do
    action :install
end

# Install Cloudera Basic:
case node[:platform]
    when "ubuntu"
        case node[:lsb][:codename]
            when "precise"
                execute "curl -s http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cdh/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -"
                execute "wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/one-click-install/precise/amd64/cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb"
            when "lucid"
                execute "curl -s http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/cdh/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -"
                execute "wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/one-click-install/lucid/amd64/cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb"
             when "squeeze"
                execute "curl -s http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/squeeze/amd64/cdh/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -"
                execute "wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/one-click-install/squeeze/amd64/cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb"
        end
        execute "dpkg -i cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb"
        execute "apt-get update"
end




if node['cloudera']['installyarn'] == true
    package "hadoop-conf-pseudo" do
      action :install
    end
else
    package "hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo" do
      action :install
    end
end


# copy over helper script to start hdfs
cookbook_file "/tmp/hadoop-hdfs-start.sh" do
    source "hadoop-hdfs-start.sh"
    mode "0744"
end
cookbook_file "/tmp/hadoop-hdfs-stop.sh" do
    source "hadoop-hdfs-stop.sh"
    mode "0744"
end
cookbook_file "/tmp/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-start.sh" do
    source "hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-start.sh"
    mode "0744"
end
cookbook_file "/tmp/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-stop.sh" do
    source "hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-stop.sh"
    mode "0744"
end
# helper to prepare folder structure for first time
cookbook_file "/tmp/prepare-yarn.sh" do
    source "prepare-yarn.sh"
    mode "0777"
end
cookbook_file "/tmp/prepare-0.20-mapreduce.sh" do
    source "prepare-0.20-mapreduce.sh"
    mode "0777"
end


# only for the first run we need to format as hdfs (we pass input "N" to answer the reformat question with No )
################
execute "format namenode" do
    command 'echo "N" | hdfs namenode -format'
    user "hdfs"
    returns [0,1]
end


# Jobtracker repeats - was the only way to get both together
%w{jobtracker tasktracker}.each { |name|
  service "hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-#{name}" do
    supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
    action [ :enable, :start ]
  end
} if !node['cloudera']['installyarn']

# now hadopp should run and this should work: http://localhost:50070:
%w(datanode namenode secondarynamenode).each { |name|
  service "hadoop-hdfs-#{name}" do
    supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
    action [ :enable, :start ]
  end
}

# Prepare folders (only first run)
# TODO: only do this if "hadoop fs -ls /tmp" return "No such file or directory"
################

if node['cloudera']['installyarn'] == true
    execute "/tmp/prepare-yarn.sh" do
     user "hdfs"
     not_if 'hadoop fs -ls -R / | grep "/tmp/hadoop-yarn"'
    end
else
    execute "/tmp/prepare-0.20-mapreduce.sh" do
     user "hdfs"
     not_if 'hadoop fs -ls -R / | grep "/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred"'
    end
end
```

So, after I create a `vagrant` vm, I try to have hadoop installed on it:

```
 knife bootstrap localhost --ssh-user vagrant --ssh-password vagrant --ssh-port 2222 --run-list "recipe[cloudera]" --sudo
```

but the only result I get is:

```
localhost The following packages have unmet dependencies:
localhost  hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo : Depends: hadoop-hdfs-namenode (= 2.0.0+1554-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.16~precise-cdh4.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
localhost                            Depends: hadoop-hdfs-datanode (= 2.0.0+1554-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.16~precise-cdh4.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
localhost                            Depends: hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode (= 2.0.0+1554-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.16~precise-cdh4.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
localhost                            Depends: hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker (= 2.0.0+1554-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.16~precise-cdh4.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
localhost                            Depends: hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker (= 2.0.0+1554-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.16~precise-cdh4.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
localhost STDERR: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
localhost ---- End output of apt-get -q -y install hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo=2.0.0+1554-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.16~precise-cdh4.6.0 ----
localhost Ran apt-get -q -y install hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo=2.0.0+1554-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.16~precise-cdh4.6.0 returned 100
localhost [2014-04-03T03:41:41+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I have had tried to install those dependencies, but it does work. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

We struggled down this path for a while and concluded that it made more sense to use vms provided by cloudera and hortonworks. Too many working parts, not enough benefit over the vendor provided vms.

There appears to be a lot of wreckage along the side of this road - people creating their own chef hadoop recipes/cookbooks. Evidence: Crowbar project, which is probably excellent, but appears to be a hopelessly complex ball of mud.

One perspective only. We would use it, if an appropriate recipe appeared. Or, cloudera and/or hortonworks could release a cookbook instead of a vm....

Answer (score 0):

Your `apt-cache` is out of date. Either manually run `apt-get update` during your bootstrap process, or add the [apt cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt) first in your run list.

Comment: Seth, I will try what you've said, but the code does run an `apt-get update` after the `execute "dpkg -i cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb"` ... do you think that's the cause?

Comment: It only runs if that check evaluates to true? Are you sure your machine is confirming it is Ubuntu? What if it thinks it's debian?

Comment: Seth, the virtual box spun up is a Ubuntu 12.04 in this case ... I could create one, login and run `uname -a` just to confirm.

Comment: Does your chef-client output confirm `apt-get update` is being run?